# whitch of these is faster method do import db?

Tags: mysql, import, command-line-interface, dump

I wonder if importing a script with mysql CLI is faster than use a Linux CLI,
let me explain what I mean here:

This:
 - `mysql -uroot -ppass` then use this `source dump_script.sql`
is faster/slower of this:
 - `mysql -uroot -ppass < dump_script.sql`

I'm importing a 9gb db and I'm trying to avoid mistake :)

Also what about http://www.percona.com/ toolkit ? there is any valid tool to fast import a db ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: There's no difference.

Both methods are limited by the insert speed of MySQL rather than the filesystem, or disk read performance. There's no difference between the two methods you state in how MySQL loads the data into the tables.

If you're importing from a dumpfile, it's a single threaded operation. If you can use a tool like MyDumper (http://www.mydumper.org/) which will restore data using several connections at once, which is significantly faster.

Comment: I'm quite sure the first one is slower, maybe because of the "verbosity" ... tested on 9gb db got 4hr difference

Comment: @Francesco: Really? I just retested on my local dev database, and there was no noticeable difference. Are you sure your environment was the same both ways? (for reference, my test was with about 4gb, innodb tables) - what do you mean by "verbosity"? You're dealing with the same dump file both ways, correct?

Comment: @Francesco - You're right, the site is down for some reason. It's an open source tool written by ex-MySQL engineers. I've been really happy with it. Try it again in a couple days, maybe they're having hosting issues.

Comment: I have the tool installed ( debian and apt :) ... however I can be used only for take a dump ( or I'm here wrong ?)